# How to do a multi-line array comprehension?

Tags: arrays, julia, list-comprehension

If I want to create an array with comprehension, but have the logic be multiple lines, how can I do that in Julia?

E.g.

`[ ...logic... for x=1:10]`

Except the logic is more clearly written in multiple lines with the last line yielding what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Generally, `do` syntax is preferred for this sort of thing, but note that this *can* be done in a regular array comprehension, you just have to wrap it in parens and use semicolons for line-breaks:

```
[(y = x + 1;
  z = y^2 + x;
  z^4 + 2y) for x in 1:5]
```

results in

```
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
     629
   14647
  130329
  707291
 2825773
```

Answer (score 4):

`map(iterator) do x` does this:

```
map(1:5) do x
    1+1         # this line is un-yielded logic that precedes the final value 
    x           # this final line is what is returned in the resulting array
end
```

results in:

```
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than a `do` block (which introduces an anonymous function which you don't need), if you want to stick with an array comprehension the cleanest way might be `begin`

```
[begin 
    y = a*b
    y-1
end for a in 1:4, b in 1:3]

4×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 0  1   2
 1  3   5
 2  5   8
 3  7  11
```

Which works nicely for a comprehension along multiple arguments too.